# Datagrid scrolling with fixed headers

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid, webforms, scroll

How can you have a fixed header on a DataGrid or GridView and allow the grid to scroll?

I'd like to avoid a solution that uses another separate table for headers.

Comment: You might want to read your own question. It probably doesn't look how you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the header in the table header is only solution that I know. I can present it here as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Scrolling tbody</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<STYLE type=text/css>TABLE {
    BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid
}
.noscroll {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: silver
}
TBODY {
    OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 130px; width: 300px;
}
TH {
    HEIGHT: 20px
}

TABLE {
    BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px
}
.container {
    BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; OVERFLOW: auto; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; WIDTH: 300px; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; HEIGHT: 150px
}
.noscroll {
    POSITION: relative
}
</STYLE>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.6000.16525" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=container>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
  <THEAD>
  <TR class=noscroll>
    <TH>Col 1</TH>

    <TH>Col 2</TH>
    <TH>Col 3</TH>
    <TH>Col 4</TH>
    <TH>Col 5</TH></TR></THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>

    <TD>2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
    <TD>4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```